# Is it possible to modify the format in xlwings given a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, xlwings

If I have the next dataframe:

```py
data1 = [['Alex',***],['Bob',12],['***',13]]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1,columns=['Name','Age'])
```

I need to pass it to an excel, the values with *** go to have red font.

Example:

```py
wb = xw.Book()
summ = wb.Sheets["1"]
summ.range('C17').options(header=False).value = df1
```

I understand that in the last line I should make the format change

Comment: You could get/set background of a column or range or font colour of text in a cell. But changing font colour based on value not sure. If you have a pre-built excel document/template with some formatting macros then it might be possible.

Comment: Thanks Nair, i will try it!